# SQL query to display aggregated data when result is zero

Tags: sql, sql-server, join, aggregate, coalesce

I have a table with fields like this:

```
Item
Category
Year 
Month
Value
```

I want to aggregate the result from this table to display sum(value) for each category, year and month. So I have this query:

```
SELECT Category, Year, Month, SUM(Value) 
FROM Table
GROUP BY Category, Year, Month;
```

This works fine, but for months in which the sum is zero, the month is not displayed. I want all months to be displayed with zero for the total value where applicable.

I’ve tried doing `COALESCE(SUM(Value),0)`, but this didn’t work.

I’ve tried creating a separate table (Table2) with the year and month values and then joining this with the first table:

```
SELECT Category, Year, Month, SUM(Value) 
FROM Table
RIGHT JOIN Table2
ON Table2.Year + Table2.Month = Table.Year + Table.Month
GROUP BY Category, Year, Month;
```

This doesn’t work either. What am I doing wrong?

Edit:

I have tried Dems's solution, using the following query:

```
SELECT
  Category.name,
  Dates.Year,
  Dates.Month,
  SUM(Data.Value) AS Value
FROM
  Category
CROSS JOIN
  Dates
LEFT JOIN
  Data
    ON  data.CategoryID = Category.ID
    AND data.Year       = Dates.Year
    AND data.Month      = Dates.Month
WHERE data.Year BETWEEN #### and ####
  AND data.Month BETWEEN # AND #
  AND data.Property IN (‘A1’,’B1’) 
  AND data.Property2 IN (‘C1’,’D1’)
GROUP BY
  Category.name,
  Dates.Year,
  Dates.Month
```

The only differences as far as can see are that I'm using a where clause on data, and have missed of the ORDER BY, which shouldn't make a difference. But I'm still having no joy.

Comment: just to confirm - sql-server?

Comment: In your original table, I am assuming that for a month with value 0, there are no entries?

Comment: Your query works for MySQL. A sum of zero is shown as such!

Comment: One should not be filtering right side of a left join in where clause, but rather in ON clause. This effectively turns left join to inner join because nulls do not satisfy any of data.* conditions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to add Category to your `Table2`, or *(even better)* have a `Category` table.

Then, you need to group by those lookup tables, not the data table.

```
SELECT
  Category.name,
  Dates.Year,
  Dates.Month,
  SUM(Data.Value) AS Value
FROM
  Category
CROSS JOIN
  Dates
LEFT JOIN
  Data
    ON  data.CategoryID = Category.ID
    AND data.Year       = Dates.Year
    AND data.Month      = Dates.Month
    AND data.Property  IN ('A1','B1') 
    AND data.Property2 IN ('C1','D1')
WHERE Dates.Year  BETWEEN #### AND ####
  AND Dates.Month BETWEEN #### AND ####
GROUP BY
  Category.name,
  Dates.Year,
  Dates.Month
ORDER BY
  Category.name,
  Dates.Year,
  Dates.Month
```

Comment: I actually do have a separate categories table, I was just trying to make the question simpler. Thanks for this, I'll give it a try. I may take a while to get back as the PC I'm working on (apart from this one!) blocks active scripts so I can't interact with Stack Overflow

Comment: I've tried this now, but it also doesn't work :-( I'm still missing the month for which there is no data.

Comment: @PaulFlowerdew - Are you ***definitely*** using `LEFT JOIN` in the order that I am? And are you ***definitely*** using the lookup tables in the `SELECT` and `GROUP BY`? *(You **must** `SELECT` and `GROUP BY` the field from the lookup tables and **not** the fields from the data table.)* Do you have a `WHERE` clause active on fields from the `data` table? Do you have additional joins, or embed this as a sub-query. This pattern is one I've used many times and should work perfectly fine... Please could I see your ***full** and **complete*** query?

Comment: See my edit above. I've checked the points you mentioned carefully.

Comment: @PaulFlowerdew - If there is no row to join on to the lookup tables, all the `data.` fields will be NULL following the `LEFT JOIN`. This means that your outer join is creating rows for the missing data, then your `WHERE` clause is filtering them out again. You have two choices, move the `WHERE` clause into the `LEFT JOIN` or reformulate the `WHERE` clause to look at the `lookup` tables and not the `data` table. I'll edit my answer to reflect. *[This is an example of why it is important to supply **all** your code when reporting issues.]*

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks so much for helping me on this, and giving me a lesson in joins too! :-)

Comment: Just one more question, related to this: If I want to additionally group the output by a field in Data, do I have to put that field in another lookup table, or is there another way of doing it?

Comment: If any field *might* be missing from the raw data, but you *need* it in the output, you need a lookup table.  Otherwise, in this case, you'll be grouping by NULLs.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT Table.Category, Table.Year, Table.Month, SUM(Table.Value) 
FROM Table
right outer  JOIN Table2
ON Table2.Year= Table.Year and Table2.Month =Table.Month
GROUP BY Table.Category,Table2.Year, Table2.Month;
```

Comment: Table2 only contains the fields Year and Month. Did you mean Table.Value?

Comment: The reason I concatenated year and month was that I wasn't sure what you'd done would work if you have more than one year, e.g. 2011, 12 to 2012, 1.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of adding adding year and month in on statement, check the condition separately for month and year. 
like this 
ON Table2.Year = Table.Year and Table2.Month = Table.Month